# linux sleep function skips output

Tags: c, linux

When executing code

```
DrawBlockWithFeatures(blockY,blockX,nextBlock[0],blockRotate);
getch();
```

[output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJSsE.png)

But executing code

```
DrawBlockWithFeatures(blockY,blockX,nextBlock[0],blockRotate)
sleep(2);
```

[There're no blocks with top of the field, shadow, recommends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjlug.png)

How to solve it? above two lines are executed in threads

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the rest of your code, too? With just these two lines, it's not possible to tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Show DrawBlockWithFeatures

Comment: Possibly missing `fflush(stdout)`?